# Quicker way for a hover state on lots of DIVs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a JSFiddle I have set up here which is a grid of boxes. On each box I want to include a hover state with some text.(Different text in each box)
I feel I have written: project1,2,3...etc when there must be a shorthand version of it.
I am new to hover-states, what is the best way to do this too?

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/8p76E/160/)

HTML:

```
<div class="projectswrap">
    <div class="project1">
      <div class="project1-hover"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="project2">
      <div class="project12-hover"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="project3">
        <div class="project3-hover"></div>
      </div>
    <div class="project4">
      <div class="project4-hover"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="project5">
      <div class="project5-hover"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="project6">
      <div class="project6-hover"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="project7">
      <div class="project7-hover"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="project8">
      <div class="project8-hover"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="project9">
      <div class="project9-hover"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="project10">
      <div class="project10-hover"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="project11">
      <div class="project11-hover"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="project12">
      <div class="project12-hover"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="project13">
      <div class="project13-hover"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="project14">
      <div class="project14-hover"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="project15">
      <div class="project15-hover"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="project16">
      <div class="project16-hover"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="project17">
      <div class="project17-hover"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="project18">
      <div class="project18-hover"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="project19">
      <div class="project19-hover"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="project20">
      <div class="project20-hover"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.projectswrap {
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.projectswrap div {
    width:50%;
    padding-bottom:48%;
    margin:0;
    float:left;
    background:rgb(204,234,236);
}
.project1-hover{ 
   position:relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.85);
    z-index:2;

}
```

Comment: The purpose of the class is that you can reuse it. Why did you give all elements a different class when you could have given them all the same?

Comment: Why not use `:hover`?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you are not using classes properly. Class denotes groups of elements with same behaviour/styling, so it makes little sense to makes unique classes for each element. So it's better to use common `project` and `project-hover` classes.

Anyway. For hover interaction you should use `:hover` pseudo-class and show `.project-hover` on `:hover`:

```css
.projectswrap {
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.projectswrap .project {
    width:48%;
    padding-bottom:48%;
    margin:1%;
    float:left;
    background:rgb(204,234,236);
    position: relative;
}
.projectswrap .project .project-hover {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0;
    left: 0; right: 0;
    background: coral;
}
.projectswrap .project:hover .project-hover {
    display: block;   
}
```

```html
<div class="projectswrap">
    <div class="project project1">
        <div class="project-hover project-hover1">Hover text #1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="project project2">
        <div class="project-hover project-hover2">Hover text #2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="project project3">
        <div class="project-hover project-hover3">Hover text #3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="project project4">
        <div class="project-hover project-hover4">Hover text #4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```